# JQuery event on scroll to position... reset on page refresh

Tags: jquery, scroll, sass, page-refresh

I'm relatively new to web development and I have a question. I have created a script that moves a menu onto the screen after scrolling past a certain point. Here's the script:

SASS:

```
nav
    position: fixed
    top: 15%
    right: -325px
    -webkit-transition: right $menu-effect-duration-slow
    -moz-transition: right $menu-effect-duration-slow
    transition: right $menu-effect-duration-slow
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var top = $(document).scrollTop();
        if(top > 450) {
            $('nav').css("right", "0px");
        } else {
            $('nav').css("right", "-325px");
        }
    });
});
```

This works perfectly, except for on page refresh. Because the default SASS position is off the screen, the menu starts off of the screen and then moves back onto the screen (if I've scrolled past the threshold). I would prefer it start in whatever position in the correct position instead of starting at the SASS default. Does anybody have any preferred methods for accomplishing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that checks your logic in your snippet that runs in `$(document).ready()`. Currently it only checks when the page is scrolled not when the page loads.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    moveNav();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var top = $(document).scrollTop();
        if(top > 450) {
            $('nav').css("right", "0px");
        } else {
            $('nav').css("right", "-325px");
        }
    });
});

function moveNav() {
  var top = $(document).scrollTop();
  if(top > 450) {
    $('nav').css("right", "0px");
  } else {
    $('nav').css("right", "-325px");
  }
}
```

You probably don't even need the `moveNav()` function, just move its contents above the `$(window).scroll()` inside the `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It turns out that your solution didn't work by itself, but deleting the "right: -325px" from the SASS and using your trick seems to do the trick!